# Find out how many parent processes a batch-file is running under

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, process, pid

I've got a batch-file that is calling itself in multiple `CMD` sessions, for example:

```
@echo off
if "%var%"=="set" goto :begin
set var=set
call cmd /c %0

:begin
echo Inside CMD session! Executed under x processes
pause
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the number of processes a batch-file is being called from.

**Normal batch file:**

```
| Batch-file
   | Batch script
```

Would return `1`, as the batch-file is being called from the root process

**Multiple process batch-file:**

```
| Batch-file
   | CMD
      | Batch-file
         | Batch script
```

Would return `2`, as the batch-file is being called from another batch-file.

A possible solution would be to get the root process identifier number (PID), and then analyse the wait chain for that process, which I'm able to accomplish easily in Task Manager:

[image: Wait chain, Task Manager]

Summary:
**How can I return the number of processes a batch-file is being executed under, with or without any third-party utilities?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%var%"=="3" goto :begin
set /A var+=1
cmd /C "%~F0"
goto :EOF

:begin
echo Inside CMD session!

wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get ExecutablePath,ParentProcessId,ProcessId > wmic.txt
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('type wmic.txt') do (
   ECHO %%a - Parent: %%b - PID: %%c
   set "Parent[%%c]=%%b"
   set "This=%%c"
)

set X=0
:nextParent
   set /A X+=1
   call set "This=%%Parent[%This%]%%"
if defined Parent[%This%] goto nextParent
echo Executed under %X% processes
```

Output example:

```
Inside CMD session!
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - Parent: 3792 - PID: 4416
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - Parent: 4416 - PID: 3220
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - Parent: 3220 - PID: 1728
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - Parent: 1728 - PID: 3560
Executed under 4 processes
```

Answer (score 1):

I dabbled with Aacini's code to have the tree more visual

```
Inside CMD session
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - 1004:12424
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -      12424:12016
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -           12016:10592
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -                10592:11392
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -                     11392:5616
Executed under 5 processes
```

Changed the middle part

```
Set "Space="
wmic process get ExecutablePath,ParentProcessId,ProcessId > wmic.txt
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('type wmic.txt') do (
   if /I "%%a" equ "%ComSpec%" (
      Call ECHO %%a - %%Space%%%%b:%%c
      CAll Set "Space=%%Space%%     "
      set "Parent[%%c]=%%b"
      set "This=%%c"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%var%"=="3" goto :begin
set /A var+=1
cmd /C "%~F0"
goto :EOF

:begin
echo Inside CMD session!
set /p Space=

wmic process get ExecutablePath,ParentProcessId,ProcessId > wmic.txt
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('type wmic.txt') do (
   if /I "%%a" equ "%ComSpec%" (
      Call ECHO %%a - %%Space%%%%b:%%c
      CAll Set "Space=%%Space%%     "
      set "Parent[%%c]=%%b"
      set "This=%%c"
   )
)

set X=0
:nextParent
   set /A X+=1
   call set "This=%%Parent[%This%]%%"
if defined Parent[%This%] goto nextParent
echo Executed under %X% processes
pause
```